# can i deploy my GWT/MGWT application with phoneGap for IOS without MAC

Tags: cordova, gwt, phonegap-build

I have my GWT/Mgwt application

-I created my Android Setup Project

-Compiled my GWT project , Placed compiled GWT output into www folder of my Android Setup project with cordova , And Everything's fine , I can see my GWT project on my Android mobile.

---

Now I want to deploy my same GWT project on my Iphone .
The setps i see they require a MAC

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.7.0/guide_getting-started_ios_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20iOS

But I'm also reading somewhere by different people that with PhoneGap You don't need to have Mac , one can deploy phoneGap Application on Iphone without MAC.

Please confirm is this Valid for GWT phoneGap Applications ?

Is there anyway I can change my GWT Web application to Iphone APP without having MAC machine.

I really need to get it confirmed before going to purchase MAC Machine

thanks

Answer (score 0):

@junaidp,

1. I don't know much about GWT, but it appears to be yet another construction framework
2. You don't need a Mac to create a iOS App, you can use PG Build (*[Phonegap Build](https://build.phonegap.com/)*) instead of using a Mac.
3. but you will need an iOS device for testing. I recommend using an iPodTouch, they are about $200
4. You will need to Apple $100/year to be a developer. I have found no way around this.
5. After you pay Apple then you can get your Apple Certificates for your iOS devices. You can only get the certificates from Apple.
6. You will need the certificate, whether you used the CLI (Command Line Interface) or PG Build.
7. You cannot deploy (test) on an iOS device with an App that does not
   have a certificate.

These articles should help

*Explanation of PhoneGap/Cordova for the Layman*
https://iphonedevlog.wordpress.com/2014/06/24/using-cordova-3-5-cli-on-mac-os-x-mavericks-to-build-ios-apps/

*Using Cordova 5.0 CLI on Mac OS X Mavericks to build iOS apps (5/2015)*
https://iphonedevlog.wordpress.com/2014/06/24/using-cordova-3-5-cli-on-mac-os-x-mavericks-to-build-ios-apps/